# How do I select multiple grandchildren in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to do something like the below, but I can't quite figure out the correct syntax of the Select line, where the grandchildren are selected.

The EventDates are a collection on the Event model.

EventDates in turn have a 1-1 EventDateVenue, and a collection of EventDateDelegates.

```
    var dataModel = DataContext.Events
                    .Include(i => i.EventDates
                       .Select(d => d.EventDateDelegates, d.EventDateVenue)
                    )
                    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == eventID);
```

I would like to access the full range of properties and object from the main dataModel.

So being able to loop through it's children, and inturn it's grandchildren.

For example:

```
var eventTitle = dataModel.Title
var eventID = dataModel.ID


foreach(EventDate eventDate in dataModel.EventDates)
{
    var venueTitle = eventDate.EventVenue.Title;
    var delegates = eventDate.EventDateDelegates;
    foreach (delegate in delegates)
    {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `.Select(d => new { d.EventDateDelegates, d.EventDateVenue })`?

Comment: The question is unclear. Maybe you need this? `Select(d => new {d.EventDateDelegates, d.EventDateVenue})`

Comment: Question unclear. I'm wondering if you're looking for .Include("EventDates.EventDateDelegatexs").Include("EventDates.EventDateVenue")

Comment: Is that any clearer?  If not, could you specify what needs clarification?  Thanks.

Comment: if you mean by selecting multiple grandchildren filtering,consider the where clause in Linq...

Comment: in your `foreach` example you say 'do something' - but what is it you want to do? Linq is for selecting/querying, not modifying, so are you trying to build up a new collection from your datamodel.events that fulfils some criteria, where that criteria is a test on the EventDateDelegates. Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Hi Mashton, thanks for your help. That was a simplified example to clarify what I was after, because a couple of comments indicated that the question was unclear. I am trying to populate a view model and grab all the data in one go.

Comment: Are you using entity framework here, and if so, what version?

Comment: Yeah, we're on EF 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody coming here in the future, here's how I did it:

```
        EventPageDataModel dataModel = DataContext.Events
            .Include(i => i.Categories)
            .Include(i => i.Dates)
            .Include(i => i.Dates.Select(d => d.EventDateDelegates))
            .Include(i => i.Dates.Select(d => d.EventDateDelegates.Select(edd => edd.User)))
            .Include(i => i.Dates.Select(d => d.Venue))
            .FirstOrDefault(i => i.URL == url);
```